# JQuery to event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, addeventlistener

I need to turn these jquery functions into event listeners and i have tried lots of different ways but i am not 100% familiar with Jquery. Can some one please help

The reason they need to be event listeners is becuase they are for a canvas drawing application and they must be able to be turned off after use as they contiuosly run once activated.

```
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
```

If they can be in the format that would be even better. The line is the button that will activate these :D thankyou

```
 var line = document.getElementById('rubber');


     line.addEventListener('click', function () {


  "content here "    

 });
```

Comment: Ignore my last (deleted) comment--sorry. You need to name the handlers so they can be turned off later.  @Jan Paepke has your solution. Turn on: $("#canvas").on("mousedown",handleMouseDown); and then turn off: $("#canvas").off("mousedown",handleMouseDown);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, what you are looking for is [jQuery.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [jQuery.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

So this is the code for you example.

```
function onClick (e) {
    console.log("content here");
}
var $line = $('#rubber')
           .on("click", onClick);
// to remove later
$line.off("click", onClick);
```

Also check out jQuery.one(), as this attaches a listener to an object and removes it after firing once.

Comment: i cant get it to work, can you try with this one please so i can see an example of what you mean please

Comment: `  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    function handleMouseDown(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      // save drag-startXY, 
      // move temp canvas over main canvas,
      // set dragging flag
      startX=mouseX;
      startY=mouseY;
      contextTemp.clearRect(0,0,canvasTemp.width,canvasTemp.height);
      $("#canvasTemp").css({ left:0, top:0 });
      isDown=true;
    }`

Comment: like this:
 `
$("#canvas").on("mousedown", handleMouseDown);
function handleMouseDown(e){
// do stuff
}
`

Comment: i cant see any difference between what i have and this?

Comment: hit enter by accident. hit refresh. :)

Comment: i have got the .on function to work however the .off doesnt turn them off for some reasin

Comment: Do you pass a function or a function reference when calling on/off?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this.

```
var el = document.getElementById('canvas');
el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    handleMouseDown(e);
}, false);

el.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    handleMouseMove(e);
}, false)

el.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
    handleMouseUp(e);
}, false)

el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e){
    handleMouseUp(e);
}, false)
```

Comment: canvas is not the actualy canvas, it is jquery

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what is exactly what you want. I think you want Event Handlers:

```
$("#canvas").mousedown(eventHandler);



function eventHandler(e){

 //do your stuff

}
```

Also I recommend you to use bind instead of shortcuts:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: the thing you posted is what i already have, do you know how to stop these functions from running then ?

Comment: Use On, Off, when you want to activate the function: `$('#rubber')
           .on("mousedown", eventHandler);` at the moment you want to stop it, `$('#rubber')
           .off("mousedown", eventHandler);` in the eventHandler function write the stuff you want to happen on mouseup. Same to mousedown etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this.

```
$("#canvas").mousedown(handleMouseDown);
$("#canvas").mousemove(handleMouseMove);
$("#canvas").mouseup(handleMouseUp);
$("#canvas").mouseout(handleMouseUp);
```